# Unidirectional OneToMany and composite key in JPA

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I have a model like so:

```kotlin
@Entity(name = "parent")
data class ParentEntity(

    @Id
    var id: Long? = null,

    @OneToMany(cascade = [(CascadeType.ALL)], fetch = FetchType.LAZY,  targetEntity = ChildEntity::class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false, )
    var children: List<ChildEntity>? = null,
)


@Entity(name = "child")
data class ChildEntity(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "application")
    val application: String?=null,

    @Column(name = "tag")
    val tag: String?=null,
)
```

Hibernate wants me to define `Id` on `ChildEntity`, so I oblige. But actually the primary key for `child` table is `(parent_id, application)`.

With the above definition, as expected, I cannot store a second parent with the same child's application.

I don't want to declare an `Generated` ID for this collection storage table.

What I would like is a `save all` on `insert` and `delete all/save all` on `update`.

Is there a way I can tell Hibernate that the actual key for table `child` is composed of the parent's ID and the other field I want?

I tried playing with `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` but it needs the parent's ID to be nullable, which I don't want either.

Comment: You cannot have a unidirectional OneToMany if the "application" column value is not unique. You will have to map the "parent_id" in the ChildEntity somehow and specify that it is using a composite primary key - there are many tutorials on this that will better describe multiple options. You'll need a key class though with the application (string) and parent_id (long) types in it at the very least, and can map the parent_id using a ManyToOne relationship mapping to ParentEntity (you can use @Id on it, no need for the PKJoinColumn), or just map it as a basic Long property.

Comment: I got it working, having `ChildEntity` as `@Embedable` and mapped as `@ElementCollection`, `@CollectionTable`, `@MapKeyColumn` in `ParentEntity`. `CollectionTable` declares a `JoinColumn` with `parent_id`, No more `@Id` in `ChildEntity`.